# If & when Interpersonal.SE rejoins HNQ, add its HNQ feed as a chat feed

Tags: feature-request, chat

Based on the discussion in [Revisiting HNQ participation for IPS](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3599/3556), it looks like IPS.SE might be rejoining HNQ.

Monitoring the questions on HNQ and ensuring they are and remain in good shape is a significant concern raised both in that discussion and in [How many questions should we allow to hit HNQ?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3602/3556).

Over on Meta.SE, [Blue has set up HNQ feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323710/152515) that track new arrivals to the HNQ list on a per-site basis. You can see the list of all feeds [here on this page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89485/hot-network-questions?tab=feeds). The RSS feed for Interpersonal.SE HNQ entries is here: https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/hnq/interpersonal.stackexchange.com

In order to help the Interpersonal community track its own HNQ activity, I suggest this feed should be added to The Awkward Silence. It should be posted as messages into chat by a dedicated bot, just like the *Introverted Meta Man* and *Extraverted Main Man* feeds. It should not be a ticker feed. The feed will only report new arrivals, so it will not spam the chat with messages.

[RPG.SE has been doing this for a couple of days now](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8925/can-we-add-the-feed-of-rpg-se-hot-network-questions-to-the-chat-feed) and so far it's been very helpful and not spammy. Users can check in on questions as they get posted into chat [by our Hot RPG Questions feed bot](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-988/hot-rpg-questions). These being posted into chat as messages means people can swing by chat just to check what's arrived after the fact.

This would be trialled first of course: if it's too spammy it can be removed or moved to a different room. But I think it would be good for IPS.SE to help it spot and address issues.

Comment: Note that I don't thing the feed is 100% accurate. We've been doing this on Mi Yodeya for a few days and it definitely missed at least one Hot Network Question https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49550359#49550359

Comment: @Alex any clue how long that one may have been on HNQ? Perhaps there's a bit of a problem with HNQ refreshing every 15 minutes and the feed being slower? IntrovertedMetaMan can take hours before posting a meta post in IPS chat, or mere minutes. I'll see if I can find something on this :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I thought of that at the time, but I don't think that's what happened in this case. The question was still Hot when I posted that comment, so using the timestamps and the earlier screenshot we can determine that it was at least Hot for well over an hour. And at that same time the feed posted a question that had only been Hot for 10 minutes. But I guess it is theoretically possible that there was a delay of several hours for the feed for that specific question, by which time it was already no longer Hot.

Comment: Even if the feed is not 100% accurate, I at least believe it's better than nothing for sites that usually produce HNQ (and sometimes a controversial one).

Comment: I vaguely remember from setting a similar feed up on A&C that it may only capture questions that appear on the first of the two pages of HNQs (viewed by 50/page). This might be worth confirming and, if a question never gets to the first page, may explain why.

Comment: Is there any page that always displays all 100 HNQs? Or any way to get all 100? (Even checking the first and second page of HNQ leaves a good chance to miss a quarter of HNQs.)

Comment: I'm not an IPS member, but I miss having IPS in my HNQ feed. Would love to have it back. Just saying.

Comment: @LN6595 You might rather visit [the discussion about whether to put it back](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3599/3556) in that case.