# HNQ 1 month anniversary - How are we doing?

Tags: discussion, hot-network-questions

As of yesterday (June 20th), it's now been one month since we were [brought back into the HNQ fold](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3648/11811) and we've had [a couple questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94066/hnq-feed) make it on the list since then. The numbers make it clear that these have resulted in an influx of visitors, votes and questions:

[image: HNQ Stats]

But what the numbers don't say is how we're handling things as a community and how well we're moderating. So with that in mind, **how are we doing?** How are we handling this influx of traffic? How do we feel about the 1 HNQ question limit?

Comment: Coming from a HNQ with no activity here - why were these removed? I tried going down the rabbit hole, but it seems to be fairly large with no end in sight.

Comment: @DeanRuiz if you're wondering why IPS was taken out of HNQ, we don't talk about that :P. There were a few question titles that made people using SO for work/professional purposes uncomfortable, and plenty of discussion here blaming HNQ for our troubles, so SE decided to take us out for a while, while they improved HNQ.

Answer (score -5):

It's nice to have more people coming into the site. Some HNQ questions seem to be relatively "easy" to handle. However, we had this question recently: [How to make clear to people I don't want to answer their "Where are you from?" question?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/22092/how-to-make-clear-to-people-i-dont-want-to-answer-their-where-are-you-from-q) And it was **really** hard to moderate (we had 16 answers, and most of them needed to be commented on and moderated).

So, if I look at how well we handle this last question I would say that we are not ready to have 2 HNQ questions in the same time. We need more people to help with moderating (especially commenting, which is IMO the hardest thing to do) before we can increase this limit.

Comment: It's interesting that you bring up the "Where are you from?" question as an example of why you don't think we can handle more. From my perspective, the question and everything brought with it were handled extremely well. Low quality answers were all deleted within hours of being posted (most of them <2 hrs!). Comments were cleaned up extremely quickly, and the question was properly protected when we felt we might receive more low quality answers. Can you specify what you think we could've done better with handling this question (if we had more man-power)?

Comment: FWIW : anytime I check IPS (many times a day, every day) I always start with the review queue. I haven't seen **any** difference using tools and moderating. No increase, no heavier workload. Nothing... I see more Q/A but they're handled ASAP by the community.

Comment: @scohe001 The commenting part was a big issue. People were receving downvotes and votes to delete but no one was available to comment and new users weren't happy with that. Yes we were good and quick otherwise but the commenting workload was a lot (at least, that's how I felt it)

Comment: @OldPadawan I have to say, I rarely review stuff because I tend to flag them/vote on them before they even get to the review queue, so I wouldn't know about that. But thank you for th insight, it's interesting

Comment: I feel like the lack of commenting points to a culture issue rather than manpower issue though, especially for moderating answers from new users.. if x% of reviewers leave comments then yes, more reviewers will mean more comments, but it's still concerning that people are delete-voting without trying to communicate to new users how to fix their post. I've kind of talked about this [with respect to "canned comments"](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3362/3171), points 1 + 3 seem relevant.